# Single onchange function for multiple controls in java script

Tags: javascript, onchange

I am new to java script and having a problem.

I am creating a form dynamically from Json string what we obtain some how ( not relevant ) - Keeping all those controls information in Array (allParamArray in code) . A control can have parent , hence a parent control can have dependents ( children )  - I want to attach onchange event to each control which have dependents . The dependents are comma separated and taken care of in the refreshDependents function.

```
<code>

for (mp = 0; mp < allParamsArray.length; mp++) { 
    if (allParamsArray[mp].dependents) {
        var parent = allParamsArray[mp].name;
        var dependents = allParamsArray[mp].dependents;
        document.getElementById(parent).onchange = function() {
           refreshDependents(parent, dependents, this.selectedIndex)
        };
    }
}
</code>
```

The Problem is , when I change value on form for a control refreshDependents has the last parent information and not of the control which I change.

I was wondering is there any way we can achieve multiple control pointing to same onchange function and in `onchange function` we get the correct information about the control which is being changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function makeHandler(parent, dependents, selectedIndex){
    return function(){
        refreshDependents(parent, dependents, selectedIndex);
    };
}

for (mp = 0; mp < allParamsArray.length; mp++) {
    if (allParamsArray[mp].dependents) {
        var parent = allParamsArray[mp].name;
        var dependents = allParamsArray[mp].dependents;
        document.getElementById(parent).onchange = makeHandler(parent, dependents, this.selectedIndex);
    }
}
```

The `makeHandler` function returns a new function object, which will keep the values that the `parent`, `dependents`, and `selectedIndex` variables had at the time it was created.

Comment: Thanks a lot , codebox_rob. just a one comment , this.selectedIndex was not available while being passed to makeHandle but i guess we can retrieve it inside refereshDependents - Hats off to you for providing the sloution. Thanks again.